# Cordova Recursive Delete is not working on Android Only

Tags: android, cordova

I am looking for a little help here. I am working on a hybrid app that creates and has the ability to delete that data. My code works perfectly in an iOS environment, but fails with "unknown error" in Android. I have checked the Android Manifest and found that the permission "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" is requested. So I am wondering if there is a problem with my code: CachePath is a variable where the data is stored

```
function deleteCacheTapped(){
//delete saved maps
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileReady, errorHandler);

function onFileReady(fs){
        fs.root.getDirectory(CachePath, {}, function(dirEntry) {
            alert(dirEntry);
            dirEntry.removeRecursively(function() {
                console.log('Directory removed.');
                alert("Cached Maps Removed");
            }, errorHandler);

        }, errorHandler);
}

function success(){
    alert("Success Files deleted");
}
function errorHandler(e) {
    var msg = '';


    switch (e.code) {
        case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
            msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
            break;
        case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
            msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
            break;
        case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
            msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
            break;
        case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
            msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
            break;
        case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
            msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
            break;
        default:
            msg = 'Unknown Error';
            break;
    };

    alert('Error: ' + msg);
}
```

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who finds this question, I found the solution by selecting a different path for Android vs iOS. Here is the code:

```
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileReady, errorHandler);

function onFileReady(fs){

    var filePath = RootPath;

    if(device.platform == 'Android'){
       filePath = '/storage/sdcard' + RootPath;
    }

    fs.root.getDirectory(filePath, {}, function(dirEntry) {
        dirEntry.removeRecursively(function() {
            success();
        }, errorHandler);

    }, errorHandler);
}
```